# Fetch a blob-type PDF saved in MySQL database

Tags: php

I am having a problem with the display of a PDF in my database mysql type blob the result that I have:

[image]

My code :

```
$document = $row['document'];
          header('Content-Type:'.$row['type']) ; 
          header('content-Description:inline;filename:"'. $row['nom_doc'] .'" ');   
          header('content-Transfer-Encoding:binary'); 
          header('Accept-Ranges:bytes');
          echo $document;
```

when I force the pdf download, I open it with this error: `Brackets does not support UTF-16 encoded text files.`

Comment: It's better to store the file on the server, and the path to it as a string in the database.

Comment: I know but that's what I was asked